# Spring Boot Constructor Injection to help testing. Why is it better than using Mockito @InjectMocks? Other benefits over field injection?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, mockito

So I see articles talking about how constructor injection can make testing easier as you can construct your dependencies with mocks in unit tests.

However this can also be achieved with @InjectMocks when using field injection. Why not just use @InjectMocks?

So if you can use @InjectMocks with field injection dependencies, are there other benefits to constructor injection over field injection when it comes to testing that I am missing?

Comment: Which is still hiding the fact that you have many dependencies. Apart from that, when using field injection you are constructing an object in an invalid state and only after setting those fields to magic (aka reflection) it is valid. This goes against OO principles the tyou shouldn't have an object in an invalid state.

Comment: Another problem is when you want to inject soething other than a mock created by by Mockito into the bean under test. SImply being able to call the constructor rather than having to use reflection makes it way simpler. Also, adding a new dependency to a constructor forces you to revisit the tests using that constructor because they don"t compile, rather than having tests failing with NPEs, or working by accident.

Comment: @JBNizet very interesting thought about making tests no longer compile, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Field injection has several drawbacks, like:

- It disallows immutable field declaration
- It eases single responsibility principle violations
- Leads to tight coupling with the dependency injection container
- Hides the dependencies (instead of being as explicit about them and declaring them as constructor parameters)

Please also see the following geat blog post about the topic: [Field injection is not recommended – Spring IOC](https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/)